# Java not all jars signed by same certificate - which is different

Tags: java, code-signing, oracleforms, jar-signing

I currently trying to run a simple Oracle forms application.
I get a message that the application was blocked to the security settings of Java.
I enabled the Java Console to see what is happening – and there I find a line in the console that the application was blocked because not all jars have the some signature certificate:

```
… are not signed by the same certificate
```

In generally I know that it is a JAR that has a different signature – how do I know which of them it is without jarsigner-checking them manually?
It's there no way in client side to check this? As it is rejecting the application to start it should say what jar or is that it's the problem...

Comment: You should add the certificate that signed the other jars in the JRE trustore.

Comment: @localghost: And which is that? How can you tell me which this is - this is the actual point of the question - I don't know which JARs got the problem - I want to know which.

Comment: You can try a command such as: `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs jar-name.jar` to get information on the certificates.

Comment: @localghost: But I would have to do this for 1000 of JAR - why JVM is not simply telling me which jars are signed with which cert or something like that.

Comment: You could write a batch script to perform the operation. Use `keytool -list` to output trusted certificates into a temporary file and then for all jars, extract certificates and check whether the fingerprint is present in the temporary file. If not, import the certificate in the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

The jars from oracle forms are standard signed by there own signature.
So frmall.jar is signed with a signature of Oracle.

If you sign you own jars by your certificate then they are different from the oracle signature and you get the above error.

The solution is to sign the jars from oracle with your own signature. Then they are all the same.

Comment: This is currently not the problem, these are signed with the certificate as well.
It's there no way in client side to check this? As it is rejecting the application to start it should say what jar or is that it's the problem...